# Angular Http Post Observable not triggering subscribe

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I am unsure if I'm fully understanding Observables in Angular as my Observable is not "triggering" or getting any information from subscribe when called. I'm making a simple login system and am trying to get a message from the Http post that it was successful, I have the following Observable function in my user service

```
addUser(user: User) : Observable<any> {
    var headers = new HttpHeaders()
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return this.http.post('http://localhost:4000/api/users/add', user,{headers:headers}).pipe(
        map((response: any) => response.json())
    );
}
```

Then I have a register component with a function, `onSubmit`, that is called when the form is submitted. This function calls `addUser` from the service to send a new user to the API and add them to the database.

```
onSubmit(): void {
    this.userService.addUser(this.user)
        .subscribe(res => {
            console.log("Registration successful");
            this.isSuccessful = true;
        },
        err => {
            console.error("Registration failed: " + err);
            this.isSignUpFailed = true;
        }
    );
}
```

The Http post call works, my API/Backend receives the data and successfully adds a user to the database. My issue is in Angular, the Observable never gives the information or response that it was successful, meaning, it never executes the following in the subscription call in the `onSubmit` function

```
console.log("Registration successful");
this.isSuccessful = true;
```

I believe this is due to a misunderstanding of Observables on my part but I am unsure of how to fix it even after looking at several other examples.

Comment: You don’t need this: map((response: any) => response.json() - unless you have a very old angular version..? Also, you don’t need the headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it had nothing to do with Angular. Silly mistake, the issue was my API was not sending any information back after it called post, it would add the data to the database but not return any kind of message which would be why the Observable did not react. Simply, I was using an Observable that called a function that manipulated data, the HTTP request, but returned nothing. My assumption was that the HTTP status would automatically return something for the Observable.

Answer (score 0):

just Remove the pipe and it will work fine there is no need for response.json

check your console you find something like these error

```
Registration failed: TypeError: response.json is not a function
```

```
addUser(user: User): Observable<any> {
    var headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
 
    return this.http
      .post("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", user, {
        headers: headers
      })
  }
```

Comment: Removed the pipe but still not getting any messages. Interestingly, if I refresh after submitting, I do get the error call from the Observer.

Comment: please check this [link](https://angular.io/guide/http) and compare your work with it

Comment: Took a look, I didn't see much difference in my post and the post examples shown in the docs link you provided. The only thing I saw that I hadn't tried was adding HTTP options in the post arguments. I tried adding observe: 'body' and response but still got nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing for people to look out for is interceptors. A project template that has authentication included creates an interceptor that will prevent calls from going unless there is a user saved. Interceptors can be tricky to find and are super powerful but can also prevent calls from running.